# Asp.net page request timeout

Tags: asp.net, timeout, request

I am working on asp.net application which had page request timeout,
I increased the timeout in HttpRuntime executionTimeout =181 , but still its not working.
Please help

Comment: Please provide more details. What does "not working" mean?

Comment: What is the application doing? If it's a long running operation, make it faster, or perform the calculations offline and cache them.

Comment: Its a online booking application and i have a wcf service which does the booking process, i have added logging in all steps for booking the timings looks good. but under high volume of traffic the asp.net UI application sometimes redirects users to Request Timeout page.

Answer (score 4):

How did you set it?

The common way is to write it in the web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="181">        
</system.web>

<compilation debug="false" />
```

Debug must be set to false otherwise the timeout will be ignored.

Don't forget to restart your AppPool or IIS.

Comment: Doesn't IIS also impose its own timeout?

Comment: Yes you are right, i have set it same. Also here are few more details Its a online booking application and i have a wcf service which does the booking process, i have added logging in all steps for booking the timings looks good. but under high volume of traffic the asp.net UI application sometimes redirects users to Request Timeout page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing the site stop while debugging / stepping through? If so, you can turn ping to disabled (i.e. Ping Enabled = False) for the application pool in IIS, which will allow you to pause / debug indefinitely.