# Setting Debug to False on aspx page not in Web.config

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to Set Debug= false for an individual asp.net page. I want to enable debugging for the entire application but there is a page in application where I want to set Debug = false only for that page ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set `Debug="false"` on the page directives, at the top of the .aspx markup.

```
<%@ Page language="C#" Debug="false" .... %>
```

Comment: Can we set executionTimeOut for an individual page like dubugging?
I tried to set executionTimeOut = 180 in httpRunTime in web.config but it still takes only 90 s ?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680018/asp-net-page-request-timeout

Comment: I read this articles many times but still I am facing the same problem. Request time out does not increase than 90 s .

Comment: Have you tried this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.scripttimeout.aspx

Comment: Yes. my web.config looks like this
<system.web>
 <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180"  requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="false">
</system.web>
i also set Server.ScriptTimeout = 180 in Page_Inite method but it still takes 90 s only.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, I believe it will be better if you create another question for the timeout issue.