# Abandon a request from inside my .NET web service that is receiving the request

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a complicated API based on .NET Framework with hundreds of endpoints and many dependencies.

I am looking for a way to abandon any request if it is not done after 10 seconds.

I am not talking about outbound requests. That is easy to do. I am talking about my own application logic that may take a long time, possibly because of dependencies or because it is waiting for resources such as CPU, ports or memory.

If, for any reason, my code is running for more than 10 seconds, I want to abandon the request. Maybe throw an exception.

I am mentioning the API has hundreds of endpoints to say that I am hoping for a more or less generic approach, maybe with a config setting or something I can attach to Startup or something like that.

It's a busy API that receives hundreds of requests per second, so it should abandon just the one request that is taking more than 10 seconds and not affect any other ongoing requests.

What are my options?

Comment: Any reason for not setting the global timeout directly? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680018/asp-net-page-request-timeout

Comment: Maybe because it doesn't run on IIS?

Comment: @Oliver If that comment is to me, where would you run ASP.NET **Framework** but in IIS?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: You're right. I was on ASP core, sorry.

Comment: It is running in an App Service Plan and we can set executionTimeout in Web.config, but it does not have the desired effect. It does not actually timeout after the given amount of seconds.